# Como deixar o fundo da página em degrade com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Seria algo parecido com a imagem abaixo; não tenho idéia de como fazer isso.

Não quero usar imagem, quero gerar com código.

[image]

Comment: Já tentou usar a propriedade `background: linear-gradient(cor1, cor2)` do css?

Answer (score 15):

### Com CSS puro

Como sugestão alternativa ao que foi perguntado, segue uma solução bem mais simples, que dispensa o uso de JS, com um CSS puro e relativamente simples:

```
body {
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF3300 0%, #EEFF00 100%);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF3300 0%, #EEFF00 100%);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF3300 0%, #EEFF00 100%);
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, color-stop(0, #FF3300), color-stop(1, #EEFF00));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF3300 0%, #EEFF00 100%);
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF3300 0%, #EEFF00 100%);
   /* conforme sugerido pelo @PapaCharlie, seguem soluções pra IE mais velho:
   /*IE7-*/ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
      startColorStr='#FF3300', endColorStr='#EEFF00', GradientType=0);
   /*IE8+*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
      startColorStr='#FF3300', endColorStr='#EEFF00', GradientType=0)";
}
```

Resultado:

[image: Gradient]

Faça seus testes no **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtbn74da/1/)**, ou use **[esta ferramenta](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/)** para gerar automaticamente o CSS para você.

### Com JS

Não vou repetir o código que já está na solução do @brasofilo (que já recebeu meu voto também), pois eu basicamente estou complementando a idéia que ele apresentou, com uma maneira de se usar a solução de degradê apresentada da resposta como imagem de fundo. Para isto, este método pode ser usado:

```
Canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

Exemplo de aplicação em JQuery:

```
$('body').css({'background-image':"url(" + Canvas.toDataURL("image/png")+ ")" });
```

> Cuidado com certas soluções supostamente em "JavaScript" pela web. Ao pesquisar alternativas externas, notei que muitas delas simplesmente geram um CSS, e o que é pior, inferior ao postado na resposta.

Comment: Ficou bacana parece completinho.

Answer (score 9):

O grande [onetrickpony tem um exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14542973/1287812) usando o elemento HTML [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas). Conforme a documentação, o elemento é suportado por Firefox 1.5+, IE 9+, Chrome e Opera 9. Para versões menores que IE 9, é necessário usar a biblioteca [Explorer Canvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/).

HTML

```
<canvas id="gradient"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
canvas#gradient {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
var
  canvas = document.getElementById('gradient'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);

gradient.addColorStop(0, '#ffffaa');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#770000');  

context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/nthv3g7h/)

[image]

Comment: Como sempre no ie não funciona :-|

Comment: @teste, lá no manual indica usar a biblioteca que adicionei na resposta para o IE.

Comment: No IE 9 canvas funciona mas `-ms-linear-gradient` não. oO

Comment: Se alguém puder testar este fiddle no IE8 ou 7? http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/nthv3g7h/3/

Comment: Vish, onde se arruma um IE desses? :) Me lembrei de épocas remotas testando no IE em N versões.

Comment: @PapaCharlie, bueno, na verdade o `@teste` disse que não roda... nem idéia onde tem esses IE, numa VM da vida :P

Comment: @brasofilo, pelo que vi não vai não

Comment: @PapaCharlie tu tendo o último IE consegues testar em qualquer versão antiga, numa opção de debug

Comment: @Jorge B., verdade, acabei de ver v7, v8 e v9. Valeu a dica, não fazia ideia disso.