# Degradê transparente sobrepondo <div> sem perder o "click"

Tags: css, css3

Como posso fazer o efeito da imagem abaixo adicionando o efeito degradê ao rodapé da `<div>` sem que essa seja feita por imagens utilizando *position absolute*?

Gostaria também de manter o degradê sem perder a função de *click* na foto do usuário.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode criar uma div com degradê de "branco transparente" para "branco sólido" - Tem vários geradores online como este aqui: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como deixar o fundo da página em degrade com JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32800/como-deixar-o-fundo-da-p%c3%a1gina-em-degrade-com-javascript)

Comment: @DorivalZanetto Sinalizei apenas pq a [própria resposta do @Bacco](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32801/20615) responde essa pergunta. Apesar do título ter JavaScript, a pergunta possui uma resposta em css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema do clique não ser barrado pelo degradê pode ser resolvido em alguns *browsers* com CSS:

```
pointer-events: none
```

porém, para fazer uma versão bastante compatível, talvez seja necessário algum JS por garantia, caso queira suportar IE menor que 11, e outros navegadores um pouco mais "antigos".

Fiz um exemplo em vermelho, apenas para facilitar a visualização e testes.
Pus links para facilitar o teste do click:

```css
#lista {
  position:relative;
}

#grad {
  pointer-events: none;   /* isto faz com que o clique "passe" adiante */  
  min-height:60px;       /* Aqui voce define o tamanho do degrade */
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
                      /* Para branco, use 255,255,255,0 e 255,255,255,1 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
                      /* Para branco, use #00ffffff e #ffffff abaixo */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff0000', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<div id="lista">
  <div id="grad"></div>
  <a href="#">Um</a><br>
  <a href="#">Dois</a><br>
  <a href="#">Tres</a><br>
  <a href="#">Quatro</a><br>
  <a href="#">Cinco </a><br>
</div>

 Veja que o clique funciona mesmo nos últimos ítens.
```

Comment: cross-browser :) +1

Answer (score 6):

Há varias formas de se fazer esse efeito porem exemplificarei duas:

**Mesclando gradiente com a imagem na propriedade *background*:**

Caso a imagem que você postou seja apenas um elemento único você pode mescla-la com o gradiente da seguinte forma:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 225, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 225, 255, 1)), center top url(http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fb/Arctic-monkeys-logo-wallpaper.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141122194620);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Usando Pseudo-elementos**:

Você pode também utilizar um pseudo elemento sob o elemento e gerar o efeito de gradiente com um dos valores sendo *transparent*:

```css
div {
  background: url(http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fb/Arctic-monkeys-logo-wallpaper.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141122194620) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}
div:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Obs.: caso queira adicionar o efeito à *tag* `<img>` a mesma não possui pseudo-elementos então aconselho que aplique-o colocando essa *tag* dentro de uma `<div>`. Caso necessite comente que adicionarei a resposta como uma terceira forma.

Para exemplificar utilizei a propriedade sem *vendor prefixes*, porem recomendo que você os utilize, você pode conferir a compatibilidade atual no [Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

Comment: Fiz uma mais simples que a sua no sentido de ser didática, mas o uso de pseudo elements me agrada para essas coisas. +1

Comment: Também gosto de utiliza-los quando preciso criar elementos "sem semântica". Obrigado pelo feedback @Bacco e +1 em sua resposta por levar em consideração a didática na mesma.

Comment: Concordo, elementos *pseudo* são ótimos pra casos como este +1

Comment: Seria interessante ter um exemplo tb com links para simular o que a AP referiu "sem perder a função de click na foto do usuário"

Comment: @Sergio, Obrigado pelo feed, elaborei minha resposta antes da edição e acabei não entendo o foco da pergunta em relação ao click, você pode ver que a primeira alternativa está focado para o gradiente considerando o conteúdo inteiro como um único elemento (no caso pensei que fosse uma unica imagem usada pelo usuário como referencia sem considerar os itens). Após isso acabei não re-editando pois a resposta do Bacco está bem completa. Você acha que seria necessário reformular minha resposta, ou posso a referenciar apenas como um possível complemento para as demais respostas que surgirem?

Comment: É melhor duas respostas completas do que uma :) Melhorar a resposta é sempre preferível. Pode ser que se explique com outras palavras e vai sempre ajudar alguém a melhorar conhecimento :)

Comment: @DorivalZanetto de fato, quando eu li a 1a vez a pergunta não percebi a questão do clique (estava só no corpo do texto na versão original). Acrescentei ao título para tentar minimizar a chance de mais gente considerar duplicata. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/98166/revisions

Comment: @Sergio, Grato pela opinião :) a melhorarei em breve!

Comment: @Bacco, exato, de começo havia entendido que o foco da pergunta era em relação ao gradiente em si sem perceber a questão do click, até pensei que pudesse ser duplicada mais relevei por causa da transparência. Por fim irei editar minha pergunta para que não fique muito fora de escopo!