# Logo precisa ficar em cima do menu mas menu nao fica clicavel

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Quando passo mouse em cima do menu a propriedade 'onMouseOver' não fica ativa pois o logo precisa estar a frente, como posso resolver? O menu com a propriedade 'onMouseOver' dimunue o tamanho tambem. grato se alguem puder ajudar.

Farra Certa

```
body {
    border: 0px;
}

div#header {
    background-image:url(../../../Documents/Sites/SiteFarraCerta/images/backgroundheader.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 1280px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;
}

img#logo {
height: 254px;
width: 373px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -186px;
z-index: 3;
}

img#box {
    height: 43px;
    width: 129px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 140px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -87px;
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
}

img#servicosbox {
    height: 43px;
    width: 129px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 682px;
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
    }

img#agendabox {
height: 43px;
width: 129px;
position: absolute;
top: 140px;
left: 424px;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
    }

img#contatobox {
    height: 43px;
    width: 129px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 811px;
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
    }

img#homebox {
    height: 43px;
    width: 129px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 295px;
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Veja se é isso que procura: [Degradê transparente sobrepondo <div> sem perder o “click”](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98166/70)

Comment: tem como enviar o link dele para entender melhor? não entendi ao certo, acho que sei resolver mas não sei se é exatamente isso, você quer um menu que muda quando poe o cursor em cima dele mas ao mesmo tempo o logotipo fica em cima do menu? seria um menu transparente em cima do logotipo ou o logotipo como background do menu?

Comment: adicionei uma foto pra entender melhor, não tenho ele hospedado

Answer (score 2):

Adicione o método `pointer-events: none;` na classe do seu logo, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
img#logo {
height: 254px;
width: 373px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -186px;
z-index: 3;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Veja como funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/LNwHV/1/

Funciona em todos os navegadores exceto do IE10 para baixo.

Espero ter ajudado ;)